Как убрать крякозябры при загрузке pdf в webBrowser из ресурса?
Uri uri = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Resources/Help.pdf");                
Stream source = Application.GetResourceStream(uri).Stream; 
this.pdfWebViewer.NavigateToStream(source);

В браузере крякозябры.

где именно в вашем коде webBrowser?

this.pdfWebViewer стандартный компонент WebBrowser

Не используйте WebBrowser, он устарел и умер (Internet Explorer 11). Если уж через браузер, то используйте WebView2.

Документация

<wv2:WebView2 x:Name="webView">

webView.Source = uri;

или так
webView.CoreWebView2.Navigate(uri.ToString());


Попробую. Но лучше бы без временного файла прямо из ресурса.

@AntonKuzmich я не изучал, но наверняка способ есть

А он есть для WPF?

@AntonKuzmich кто именно есть?

@AntonKuzmich я только не до конца понимаю. Если у вас встроенный в ресурсы (а значит неизменяемый) контент, почему его сразу бы не сверстать просто как XAML страницу и не возиться с PDF файлами? Есть ещё FlowDocument https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/flow-document-overview

PDF используется для хелпа. И файл может измениться.

Файл в ресурсах приложения после его сборки не может измениться.

Ну можно будет заменить файл в проекте на более новый и отбилдить

@AntonKuzmich Точно также можно внести изменения в проект просто подверстав документ прямо в проекте без использования PDF. Вы тащите огромную сложную машину "браузер" в проект только ради того чтобы работать с этим форматом файла. Есть же более лёгкое решение.

@AntonKuzmich удалось разобраться?

Пока что нет. Сторонние компоненты не всегда подходят по фреймворку и порой не оправдывают доверия.

@AntonKuzmich каким местом WebView2, выпущенный вместе с браузером Edge  компанией Microsoft сторонний?

Поставил WV2 вроде работает
